# Optimising max number of threads running on a CPU

Tags: java, multithreading

Just wondering what is the best way to decide when to stop creating new threads on a single-core machine which is running the same program multiple times as a thread?

The threads are fetching web content and doing a bit of processing, which means the load of each thread is not constant all the way until the thread terminates.

I'm thinking to have a thread which monitors the CPU/RAM load, and stop creating threads if the load reaches a certain treshold, but also stop creating threads if a certain threads count has been reached, to make sure the CPU doesn't get overloaded.

Any feedback on what techniques are out there to achieve this?

Many thanks, 
Vladimir

Comment: I think you are on the right track.  One thing to consider is to use NIO and selectors so your threads are always busy as opposed to always waiting for IO.  It's going to be hard to maximize throughput without having peaks and valleys otherwise.

Comment: There, Gray beat me to it :) With blocking IO you're going to need a ridiculously large amount of threads which will be wasting RAM and doing mostly nothing but wait.

Comment: You may not want to create the threads yourself. Use `ExecutorService`, which reuses threads for `Runnable` or `Callable` tasks and reduces the overhead of creating an destroying threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is going to be difficult to do this by monitoring the CPU used by the current process.  Those numbers tend to lag reality and the result is going to be peaks and valleys to a large degree.  The problem is that your threads are mostly going to be blocked by IO and there is not any good way to anticipate when bytes will be available to be read in the near future.

That said, you could start out with a `ThreadPoolExecutor` at a certain max thread number (for a single processor let's say 4) and then check every 10 seconds or so the load average.  If the load average is below what you want then you could call `setMaximumPoolSize(...)` with a larger value to increase it for the next 10 seconds.  You may need to poll 30 or more seconds between each calculation to smooth out the performance of your application.

You could use the following code to track your total CPU time for all threads.  Not sure if that's the best way to do it

```
    long total = 0;
    for (long id : threadMxBean.getAllThreadIds()) {
        long cpuTime = threadMxBean.getThreadCpuTime(id);
        if (cpuTime > 0) {
            total += cpuTime;
        }
    }
    // since is in nano-seconds
    long currentCpuMillis = total / 1000000;
```

Instead of trying to maximize the CPU level for your spider, you might consider trying to maximize throughput.  Take the sample of the number of pages spidered per a unit of time and increase or decrease the max number of threads in your `ExecutorService` until this is maximized.

One thing to consider is to use NIO and selectors so your threads are always busy as opposed to always waiting for IO.  Here's a [good example tutorial about NIO/Selectors](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/selectors.html).  You might also consider using [Pyronet](http://code.google.com/p/pyronet/) which seems to provide some good features around NIO.

Comment: I was wondering.I clicked on `Pyronet` and it has around 150 downloads.Why would someone include a library with so small user base as part of a project?

Comment: Before there's no alterative and you don't want to re-invent the wheel @Cratylus.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

If async I/O is not a good fit, I would consider using thread pools, e.g. [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html), so you don't have the overhead of creating, destroying and recreating threads.

Then I would do performance testing to tweak the max number of threads offers the best performance.

You could start with 10 threads, then rerun your performance test with 20 threads until you hone in on an optimal value.  At the same time I would use system tools (depending on your OS) to monitor the thread run queue, JVM, etc.

For the performance test you would have to ensure that your test is repeatable (i.e. using the same inputs) and representative of the actual input that your program would be using.